# Convert LaTeX formula to computable function

Tags: pdf

I'm reading a paper, that has solved systems of linear equations and has written the expressions for the solutions in a table format. I would like to turn these expressions into code I could compute in Python (or another programming language), and I was wondering if there is some way to automate the process. Can I convert LaTeX formulae (obtained from a PDF) into a computable function?

As an example, I'd like to convert the LaTeX formulae

[image]

into the Python code

```
    h
    (3/16)*(35*A+2*C-48*h)
    (-5/8)*(21*A+2*C-24*h)
    (7/16)*(15*A+2*C-16*h))
```

Comment: convert latex (to anything) normally implies you have the sources, if you just have the pdf then there is very little record of it ever being tex. You could OCR the formular with mathpix and try to get tex from it then getting from the tex to python is (in small cases like this) just a matter of applying enough regexp )from eg python)

Comment: See for some related questions https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ocr.

Comment: or better actually get wolfram mathematica syntax rather than tex from mathpix https://docs.mathpix.com/?python#formatting-options

Comment: But for equations like these just copy-pasting from the PDF in your viewer probably gets you already close to the desired result, although the fractions may be wrong.

Comment: And as an applied mathematician, expressions optimized for calculations often have little resemblance to standard notation.